# Converted apache arrow file from data frame gives null while reading with arrow.js

Tags: python, node.js, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I converted one sample dataframe to `.arrow` file using `pyarrow`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [10, 2, 3]})
df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'],errors='coerce')
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
writer = pa.RecordBatchFileWriter('test.arrow', table.schema)
writer.write_table(table)
writer.close()
```

This creates a file `test.arrow`

```
df.info()
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
    Data columns (total 1 columns):
    a    3 non-null int64
    dtypes: int64(1)
    memory usage: 104.0 bytes
```

Then in NodeJS I load the file with arrowJS.
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/js/

```
const fs = require('fs');
const arrow = require('apache-arrow');

const data = fs.readFileSync('test.arrow');
const table = arrow.Table.from(data);

console.log(table.schema.fields.map(f => f.name));
console.log(table.count());
console.log(table.get(0));
```

This prints like

```
[ 'a' ]
0
null
```

I was expecting this table will have a length 3 and `table.get(0)` gives the first row instead of `null`.

This is the table scehem looks like `console.log(table._schema)`

```
[ Int_ [Int] { isSigned: true, bitWidth: 16 } ]
Schema {
  fields:
   [ Field { name: 'a', type: [Int_], nullable: true, metadata: Map {} } ],
  metadata:
   Map {
     'pandas' => '{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "stop": 5, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "columns": [{"name": "a", "field_name": "a", "pandas_type": "int16", "numpy_type": "int16", "metadata": null}], "creator": {"library": "pyarrow", "version": "0.15.0"}, "pandas_version": "0.22.0"}' },
  dictionaries: Map {} }
```

Any idea why it is not getting the data as expected?

Comment: Can you write to one of the project's mailing lists or open a JIRA issue? We can help you more there

Comment: @WesMcKinney I am not in the . mailing list, please give me the link to JIRA I can create an issue.

Comment: Looking at the doc for arrowJS it looks like you have to do `const table = arrow.Table.from([data]);`

Comment: @WesMcKinney I think this is a regression in pyarrow 0.15. I can reproduce this with pyarrow `0.15.0-py37h8b68381_0` on conda-forge, but rolling back to `0.14.1-py37h8b68381_2` works.

Comment: Raised a JIRA ticket for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a format change in Arrow 0.15, as [mentioned by Wes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6921?focusedCommentId=16953979&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16953979) on the Apache JIRA. This means that *all* Arrow libraries, not just PyArrow, will surface this issue when sending IPC files to older versions of Arrow. The fix is to upgrade ArrowJS to 0.15.0, so that you can round-trip between other Arrow libraries and the JS library. If you can't update for some reason, you can instead use one of the workarounds below:

Pass `use_legacy_format=True` as a kwarg to `RecordBatchFileWriter`:

```py
with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter('file.arrow', table.schema, use_legacy_format=True) as writer:
    writer.write_table(table)
```

Set the environment variable `ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT` to 1:

```bash
$ export ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT = 1
$ python
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> table = pa.Table.from_pydict( {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]} )
>>> with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter('file.arrow', table.schema) as writer:
...   writer.write_table(table)
...
```

Or downgrade PyArrow to `0.14.x`:

```bash
$ conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow=0.14.1
```